# How to use AIML with python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.6, aiml

I'm trying to use `aiml` in Python 3.6, I am using `aiml` library for it, but there is a problem with what I expected and what I got!!
for every input, it's showing me

> "WARNING: No match found for input: hello(this is input)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always look at programy, full Python 3 from the ground up and supports 3.6 and 3.7 and above

Comment: Didn't what you said !! Please clarify

Comment: Try Program-y https://github.com/keiffster/program-y full Python 3 and aiml 2.1 compliant

Answer (score 0):

Seems that https://pypi.org/project/python-aiml/ hasn't got support for Python 3.6

When this happens, I usually search in the Network Graph of Github, some fork that have already solve the problem: https://github.com/paulovn/python-aiml/network

You can try the weddige's fork: https://github.com/weddige/pyaiml3